# Laravel file upload to CentOs Server and upload directory

Tags: laravel

New to `laravel`, using the `latest version` of laravel, created an app and deployed to the server as per the documentation [here](https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6). I am using `Intervantion` to resize the uploaded images. As per the documentation this is what I did

1. Uploaded complete project in the `/home/username/laravel-project/` which is in the same directory as `public_html`
2. Under `public_html` I moved all the files from `/home/username/laravel-project/public` and deleted the `public` folder from `/home/username/laravel-project/`
3. I have modified the `env` file with server's mysql credentials

> How I am uploading and resizing the images with Intervention in the controller

```
$save_path = 'product-images/';
$image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath());              
$image_resize->resize($width, $height);
$image_resize->save(public_path($save_path .$newFileName));
```

> filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],
    'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
    's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
],
],
```

***Issue 1***:- When I upload the images I got the error `Can't write image data to path (/home/username/laravel-project/public/product-images/15758646011-500x550.jpg)`. When I recreate the `public` folder under `/home/username/laravel-project/` and created `product-images` folder with `777` permission it worked, but I don't know this is the place where the images needs to be stored or the images needs to be stored in `public_html/project-images`

***Issue 2:-*** After I have solved the uploading issue as mentioned in `Issue 1` when I tried to view the uploaded images, the images are not showing, I noticed the URL of the images are `http://example.com/product-images/15758632231-500x550.jpg`. I tried to open the URL in a separate window and got `404 not found`. I am retrieving the product images using the code `return url('product-images/'.$value);` where `$value = 15758632231-500x550.jpg` which is coming from the database

Answer (score 0):

For the **Issue 1**:

- First you'll need to create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` by running this command:

  ```
  php artisan storage:link
  ```
- You need to store the images in the `storage\app\public\images` folder by this code:

  ```
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

  Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);
  ```

This is from [Laravel's Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files)

- Never use `777` permissions in public directory for security purposes.

For the **Issue 2**:

- You can use the `Storage` facade in order to get the URL of the file.
  [File URL](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-urls)
  You can write the code like this.

  ```
  $url = Storage::url('file.jpg');
  return $url;
  ```